# NetworkX accessing nodes with multiple node attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

A question with a nearly identical title exists on SO, but it's a very different question.  My question is about nodes each having multiple attributes, but a different set of attributes, and selecting nodes based on those attributes hierarchically.

Specifically, I want to select a particular node of a particular type based on its type and name attributes, but some types don't have the name attribute.

So, for the following network
    import networkx as nx

```
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(0, 4):
    G.add_node(i)

attrs = {0:{'type':'A', 'name':'Amy'}, 1:{'type':'A', 'name':'Bob'}, 2:{'type':'B'}, 3:{'type':'B'}, 4:{'type':'C'}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, values=attrs)

print([node for node,attr in G.nodes(data=True) if ((attr['type']=="A") & (attr['name']=='Amy'))][0])
```

What I expected was for it to print out the node index for the first node `0`, but instead I get `KeyError: 'name'`.

In most of Python, logical conditions are processed from left to right, so that the second condition is only evaluated if the first condition evaluates to `True` (it works in Pandas), but that seems not to be the case here.

For example, it works if I first create a subgraph of my graph by type:

```
H = G.subgraph([node for node,attr in G.nodes(data=True) if attr['type']=="A"])
print([node for node,attr in H.nodes(data=True) if attr['name']=='Amy'][0])
```

Because all the nodes of type A have the name property, I no longer get the error when I search by name in graph `H`, but NetworkX must be evaluating both logical conditions when I try to do this in one step on graph `G`.

So accessing attributes of types and subtypes quickly becomes a huge pain and memory hog if I have to make a subgraph for every type and subtype of node in my graph.

Is there a better way to extract particular nodes (or groups of nodes) based on attributes that only some nodes have in a hierarchical fashion to avoid this problem?  I like using list comprehension, but obviously it may not work here, so I'm certainly open to other ways around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any `networkx` graph element attributes are stored in a common Python dict:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, waka=1)
G.nodes(data=True)[1]
```

> `{'waka': 1}`

So if you don't want to raise `KeyError` exceptions, you can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) function instead of dict element access:

> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

---

**Here is the example:**

This code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, waka=1)
G.add_node(2, waka=2)
G.add_node(3, attr='Q')
print([
    node
    for node, attr in G.nodes(data=True)
    if ((attr['waka'] != 1) & (attr['attr'] == 'Q'))
][0])
```

will raise `KeyError`:

> `KeyError: 'attr'`

And this code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, waka=1)
G.add_node(2, waka=2)
G.add_node(3, attr='Q')
print([
    node
    for node, attr in G.nodes(data=True)
    if ((attr.get('waka') != 1) & (attr.get('attr') == 'Q'))
][0])
```

will work:

> `3`